# Can I connect ESP32 GPIO to USB D+ and D- through a CH340 converter?

Tags: usb, esp32, keyboard

I want to see what a wired keyboard (and later a mouse) outputs to an ESP32, so I am thinking of connecting a wired keyboard's USB to a CH340 (USB to UART) converter and then connect it to GPIOs of an ESP32-WROVER. After that I will `serial.read()` those GPIOs and see what the serial monitor outputs.

Will that work? Will I get parsable data?

Answer (score 1):

No. It won't work. CH340 is not an UART to USB host, it is a USB UART device.

Keyboard and CH340 are both USB devices. They can't communicate between each other in any way. USB host is required to communicate with USB devices.